# Cannot make javafx Ensmble work

Tags: java, javafx, ensemble-learning

I have some problems viewing the ensemble in my browser (running Win10, tried Edge, IE, and Firefox), it requires me to download Java, but I have already done that.

I did search some info about how to make Java work in my browser and I set the Java "enable Java content in the browser" setting.

Is it failing because of environment variables or something?

Answer (score 0):

Java in the browser is very close to [deprecation by Oracle](https://jaxenter.com/clock-ticking-java-browser-plugin-will-deprecated-soon-131546.html) and already is prevented by default by many browser vendors.  At this stage, I do not believe it is worth investing your time to show the Ensemble application in a browser.  There are other [packaging and deployment options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html#BABCIBAD) for JavaFX applications which are more reliable than trying to deploy into a browser.

FWIW, you can at least check if Java will run in a given browser by following the instructions at [java.com](https://java.com/en/), if that works (and its not guaranteed to for most modern browsers), then Ensemble in the same browser should also work.